# Write an appropriate SQL query to determine which album has the longest play length (total track duration)

Tags: sql

I try to put the same that my lecture did but doesn't work
tables inputs:

[image]

[image]

Queries:

```
SELECT T1.TRACK_NAME, T1.TRACK_DURATION
FROM TRACKS T1 
INNER JOIN TRACKS T2 ON T1.TRACK_ID = T2.TRACK_ID
WHERE T1.TRACK_DURATION = T2.TRACK_DURATION
ORDER BY T1.TRACK_DURATION;


SELECT T1.TRACK_NAME, T1.TRACK_DURATION
FROM TRACKS T1 
INNER JOIN TRACKS T2 ON T1.TRACK_ID = T2.TRACK_ID
WHERE T1.TRACK_DURATION = T2.TRACK_DURATION
ORDER BY T1.TRACK_DURATION;
```

They show all the tracks and duration

The exercise is that:
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrAqF.png)
But the *sample* results must be this way:

```
  TRACK_NAME TRACK_DURATION
   Find You    3,5 
   Friends.    3,5 
   Silence     3,5 
   Rain         4 
   What About Us 4
```

Comment: more details required, like input expected output, what is the logic you are using and most basic your table schema.

Comment: and what is your output?

Comment: There's no reason to join `tracks` to `tracks`. And you query doesn't even include the `albums` tables (or at least `album_id`) which is clearly going to be important. I suggest re-reading your textbook and notes because this a pretty basic query.

Comment: can you help to solve?

Comment: You're asking two different questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the title of your question, this query will give you the title and total duration of the album with the longest total duration of its tracks:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ALBUM_TITLE, SUM(TRACK_DURATION) AS TotalDuration 
FROM ALBUMS a 
    INNER JOIN ALBUM_TRACKS at ON at.ALBUM_ID = a.ALBUM_ID
    INNER JOIN TRACKS t ON t.TRACK_ID = at.TRACK_ID
GROUP BY ALBUM_TITLE
ORDER BY SUM(TRACK_DURATION) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your pick:

```
select * from tracks as t where exists (
    selecdt 1 from tracks as t2
    where t2.track_id <> t.track_id and t2.track_duration = t.track_duration
)
order by t.track_duration, t.track_name;

select distinct track_name, track_duration
from tracks as t inner join tracks as t2
    on t2.track_id <> t.track_id and t2.track_duration = t.track_duration
order by t.track_duration, t.track_name;

select track_name, track_duration
from tracks
where track_id in (
    select track_id from tracks groups by track_duration having count(*) > 1
)
order by track_duration, track_name;
```